# Some react-native vector icons are not shown

Tags: react-native

I'm building an application and I have a
problem with react-native icon. This is an image of the problem.

[image]

I followed [this link](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#icon-component) and then I made sure the font is copied to android/app/src/main/assets/fonts, deleted the android/app/build folder. Finally I restarted react native package, but not throwing good result it such as first. How to fix this problem?

This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Image, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { Container, Header, Content, Card, CardItem, Right, Left, Thumbnail, Body, Text, Button, Icon } from 'native-base';

export default class SideMenu extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <Container style={{ flex:1, backgroundColor:'#fcfcfc' }}>
                  <Content>
                      <Body style={{ justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                          <Image style={{ position: 'relative'}}  source={require('../../../image/imac.jpg')}/>
                          <View style={bao.cover}>
                              <Thumbnail square source={require('../../../image/ava.jpg')} style={{borderRadius:40}}/>
                              <Text style={{ color:'#fff', flex:1, lineHeight:40, fontSize:18 }}> Vu Nguyen </Text>
                          </View>
                      </Body>
                      <Card>
                          <CardItem>
                              <Icon name="home" />
                              <Text>Home</Text>
                          </CardItem>
                          <CardItem>
                              <Icon name="news" />
                              <Text>Home</Text>
                          </CardItem>
                      </Card>
                  </Content>
          </Container>
        );
    }
}
const bao = StyleSheet.create({
    cover:{
      position:'absolute',
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'row',
      marginLeft:30,
      top: 170
    }
})
```

Comment: What's the icon name you gave?

Comment: My icon is "news"

Comment: Do you can fix above problem ?

Comment: make sure that name is there in whatever **Icon set** you are using like (FontAwesome, Ionicons) etc

Comment: Which icon set are you using ?

Comment: I am using Ionicons with tag is: <Icon name ="news" />

Comment: link for your understand https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/

Comment: go to http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/ionicons/. Only icons available there can be used in the app. There is no icon with name "news" in Ionicons

Comment: news icon is available in Entypo not Ionicons. Hope this helps :)

Comment: god bless you, thanks for your the enthusiasm

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is facing this issue please paste this line in your app/build.gradle and re-run the project.

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the icon name you are is there in whatever **Icon set** you are using like (FontAwesome, Ionicons) etc.
"news" icon is available in [Entypo](https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/)

Answer (score 1):

The issue was solved for me by:

```
react-native link
```

and then:

```
react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where the node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/glyphmaps/FontAwesome5Pro.json was outdated.  I was trying to get the "bible" icon from FontAwesome v5.3.1, however resources from react-native-vector-icons still seem to be from 5.0.  So a "?" was appearing.

I tried to npm install the latest version of react-native-vector-icons, but the problem persisted.

I manually copied the FontAwesome5Pro.json content from [the Github repo](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/tree/master/glyphmaps).  After restarting my simulator the question marks had become the icons I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

it's because native-base have some icons and some are not present.

so try to import the icon from it's original module instead of native-base

try this

```
import Icon from 'react-native-ionicons'
```

or other font libraries

```
import Icon from 'react-native-fontawesome'
```

instead of this

```
import { Icon } from 'native-base'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
react-native link react-native-vector-icons
```